# Creating a C# program that will paste my data into a specific MS word

Tags: c#, copy, paste, clip

I wanted to create a simple C# program that acts like a "paster" to a specific doc. Example, I will copy a text through a conventional button and then I will press a button in my C# program and the program will paste the data that I copied into a doc file. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Here are two links I googled on how to create and append to a word doc.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6b9478cs.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/660478/Csharp-Create-and-Manipulate-Word-Documents-Progra